What is a production use case for directly instantiating a pod?
In my understanding the proper way to run anything in Kubernetes is to use a Deployment, which takes care of replicas, upgrades, downgrades, number of pods, versioning, etc.
What is a valid use case, other than for the purposes of training or studying, to instantiate a Pod (or even a ReplicaSet, for that matter) directly?

"I'm writing my own controller that does all of the same lifecycle things a Job or Deployment does, but differently."

@DavidMaze: so basically there are specific custom deployments written? What k8s offers is not always sufficient?

I don't have a specific example in mind, but Jobs, ReplicaSets, DaemonSets, and StatefulSets are all backed by Go controller loops that manage Pods, and it'd be reasonable to do the same if you had a need for it.

I don't understand why this question is "Opinion Based"

Technically the recommendation is correct -- pods should normally only be created using deployments, but for one-off, temporary instances, directly creating a pod (and maybe quicker) can be used.
For example, I would create a pod directly for a quick debug from inside a kubernetes cluster using something like:
kubectl run $ARGS -i --tty debug-pod --image=debian -- bash
I can then quit out of the pod and kubectl delete debug-pod when I'm done.
This is useful to test a ClusterIP service or something that can only be accessed from within the cluster, or debugging why a pod can't access an external service, perhaps due to IP or some other error.
